# How to sort one item to match another but applying the sort elsewhere?

Tags: python, string, sorting

For example say I have the word and arbitrary string

```
LEAST HDKEN
```

Now say I rearrange LEAST to STEAL. I want to apply that same "transformation" to the second word.

```
STEAL ENDKH
```

So since the L (first character) in LEAST went to the end (of STEAL), the first character of the string (H) therefore goes to the end position as well. Similar goes for the rest.

Comment: what happens when there're duplicate characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Zip the two strings together so that you sort pairs of letters. Then sort, and unzip.

```
>>> zip(*sorted(zip('LEAST', 'HDKEN'), key=lambda s:'STEAL'.index(s[0])))
[('S', 'T', 'E', 'A', 'L'), ('E', 'N', 'D', 'K', 'H')]
```

or, a bit longer:

```
# Make pairs of letters
pairs = zip('LEAST', 'HDKEN')
# Sort pairs, using the index into STEAL as the sort key
sortedpairs = sorted(pairs, key=lambda s:'STEAL'.index(s[0]))
# Unzip the pairs back into words
result = zip(*sortedpairs)
# Print the words
print ''.join(result[0]), ''.join(result[1])
```

(prints `STEAL ENDKH` as desired)

Comment: I technically just want ENDKH, but this is amazing. How does this work?

Comment: @KaliMa: I added a bit of explanation.

Comment: I understand the zip and unzip, and the basics of sort keys, but why 'STEAL'.index(s[0])?

Comment: `sorted(pairs, key=lambda s: 'STEAL'.index(s[0]))` is admittedly a little bit magic. But basically, it specifies a *sort key*, which is like specifying precisely what order you want to sort the elements in. Every element is compared according to the key, instead of its original value. All I'm doing is telling `sorted` that it should sort the pairs according to the first element's (`s[0]`) position in the word `'STEAL'` (`'STEAL'.index(s[0])`).